# PHP won't echo html code to show a link on page

Tags: php, hyperlink, echo

I have a simple echo statement that's supposed to display a link on the web page, but all it's doing is showing exactly "`<a href=website.com>Link</a>`" (without the quotes). To me, this should work with no problem. I thought maybe it's because the HTML for the website is in one file while the PHP is in another file.

```
foreach ($output as $output)
{
    echo 'DATE: ' . $output['date'] . "\n";
    echo 'TO: ' . $output['to'] . "\n";
    echo 'FROM: ' . $output['from'] . "\n";
    echo 'SUBJECT: ' . $output['subject'] . "\n";
    echo "<a href=website.com>Link</a>\n\n";
}
```

Comment: What do you expect it to display?

Comment: `foreach ($output as $output)` DISASTER. Take an array, overwrite it with ONE of its occurances - then see where the loop get you :)

Comment: Please don't change the question invalidating answers.

Answer (score 2):

Your loop isn't a valid one, you have `$output as $output`.

I also suggest printing `$output` before looping through it, to see if it even contains what you think it should.

Comment: The loop works because `foreach` makes a copy, but you destroy your original array: https://3v4l.org/5oesQ

Comment: @AbraCadaver Sounds like a terrible design choice either way :)

Comment: None of this is relevant to the question.

Comment: This is actually an applicable answer to the first version of this question.

Answer (score 1):

In your 'a' tag, the actual URL needs to be in quotes

```
<a href='http://www.website.com'>
```